# Avoid reboot of USB serial device when another USB device is inserted

Tags: usb, reset, serial-bus, insertion

**EDIT 7/7/2018:**

Can't add an answer because this question is closed however there is an answer [here](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection).

It is not a problem related to Windows only. The reset is caused by hardware behaviour, the microcontroller itselfs, detects a change and reboots.

I still don't know why the USB serial needs to be reset when a new USB device is inserted or unplugged. It also happen when you insert or unplug, for example an USB mouse. Strange.

---

---

I have two Arduino compatible usb serial (with CH341 serial IC) devices on an USB hub built into an enclosure, an ESP8266 and a ATMega32u4 (Pro mini) board.

Both devices can be switched on or off (by switching +5V and +D lines on or off), so it will be connected or disconnected from/to the USB hub.

The devices can find and talk to eachother via I2C, works pretty OK. The USB hub is connected to a PC with Windows 7 OS.

The problem: It is very annoying that when you power one of the two on, and one of the two is already on, it also 'resets' (reset cause the MCU to warm reboot) the one that was on.

---

```
Switched:      state other switch:   state ESP8266:        state ATMega32u4:      cause:    
 S1:OFF to ON   S2:ON                 off and turns on      is on because S2:ON    ATMega32u4 reset, why?
 S2:OFF to ON   S1:ON                 is on because S1:ON   is off and turns on    ESP8266 reset, why?
```

---

Especially the ESP2866 is annoying, because it has some work to do to connect (take some time) etc.

It has nothing to do with spikes on the bus, hub reset etc, you see the same behaviour when inserting such devices directly into your PC, all same devices will be reset for some reason.

Is there a way to avoid this and why does it happen anyway?

---

**Situation Visualization**

---

[image: Situation]

Comment: You're giong to need to be more specific as to what you mean by "reboot".  Also, the ESP8266 is not a USB device, so you're going to have to explain how that is connected to a USB bus.

Comment: I second the Chris's request. What do you mean "when another is inserted"? Inserted where? ESP 8266 is a sort of co-processor, and has only UART interface. Are you hot-plugging (inserting) the ESP8266 SoC module into some port of ATMega32u4? Or do you have another UART-to-USB bridge for the WiFi module? Which "internal hub" do you mean? Schematic/block diagram please.

Comment: @Both above: Changed the title of the question. I know the ESP8266 is not a USB device, however, use it on a board with an USB to serial interface like NodeMCU for example. To program you need this interface, at least once. There are many versions around so I used only the MCU name in the question. In the first line I stated that it is combined into one device including an UBS hub. Hopefully this clarifies a few things.

Comment: Just adding a 'schematic'.

Comment: So you're trying to solve power glitches going over the i2c?

Comment: Even with the edit, it's still too far from clear what you mean.  What is this "power/usb switch" - is it a switch that is opening?  If not, remove it from the system to simplify the situation.  If it is opening, you need to explain the causes which can make it do so or provide full documentation of the device.

Comment: Then on your ESP8266, you need to explain if there are any lines from the CH341 to the ESP8266 reset.  And on the ATmega side - do you really have a 32u4 connected to a USB-serial rather than having its own native USB interface connected to the USB??  If so, again you need to document any connections to its reset, and if not you need to be extremely specific about the software running in it.

Comment: Finally, the question remains: **What do you meant by "reboot" ???** you've yet to explain exactly what you mean or how you know that this is happened, so we don't know if you mean a software reset, a hardware reset, or merely some program logic causing behavior to change in response to some electrical or protocol event.

Comment: Guys, guys, common, this is an electric engineering site eh? Rebooting is in computerland rebooting of the system some kind similar to reset. Why I need to explain everything and draw the lines to everything...... Take a look at this, it is just a board with all components, a NodeMCU and a Leonardo. However, that;s not the point, it is about re-initialization of the devices when one is inserted, common, do not deduce topic. I tried to keep it simple. Take a look at the first answer, it seems to be perfectly clear.

Comment: USB hubs usually have more than one port, this is the purpose of USB hubs. Each port is meant to be connected to an individual USB device. Your diagram shows some fork to a single USB port. Yes, it is an electrical engineering site,  so sloppiness is not appreciated. What is it, the fork?

Comment: @Codebeat - no, rebooting in EE land is not a simple topic at all.  There are at least 3 *real* forms, and at least 2 other things that could look like that from the outside.  Since you refuse to help figure out which is happening, or to even clearly document your setup, you cannot receive definitive help.

Comment: *"Take a look at the first answer, it seems to be perfectly clear"*.  The answer, unfortunately, is totally wrong.

Comment: @Ali Chen: At least he understood the question, what's going on, that's perfectly clear. Don't ruin the context.

Comment: Changed the image, satisfied?

Comment: @Codebeat, picture for ports is fine now. You still need to explain what exactly is the "power/usb switch". Now you need to detail the scenario(s) that cause your concerns. Say, you have AtMega connected, enumerated, and COM interface running through the embedded hub (BTW, what kind? How it is hooked up?). Then what?

Comment: Get  a decent hub, problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Windows re-enumerates the tree on each UHCI controller when a device is inserted. You can read [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/usbcoreblog/2009/10/30/how-does-usb-stack-enumerate-a-device/) for a good description of the process.
I assume the process is very similar in Linux.

If you want to avoid re-enumeration, then connect the two devices to a separate USB controller/Hub tree.
Remember that most USB PC controllers actually have two UHCI controllers, so you will probably find your rear and front ports show up under different UHCI Roots. You can experiment using front and rear ports to begin with.

Comment: Windows (or else) doesn't re-enumerate "the tree", it enumerates **only the newly** connected device, by following the protocol described in the MS article. System assigns to the new device any available address, usually N+1, and moves on. All previously connected and enumerated devices remain fully functional. Please delete your answer, it is completely wrong.

Comment: @AliChen, you are right in an ideal world. However this is a common problem seen by USB developers. Typically caused by poor endpoint firmware. Let's see if it fixes the Ops question (I think it will) before I delete it.

Comment: This is not an ideal world, there are billions of hubs and devices that work as I described. Bad endpoint firmware, if any, is affecting only one device, the one that is new. All other already enumerated devices will remain unaffected, unless you short the power of the tree by, say, huge inrush current. Your advice to connect the devices to different controllers will likely "solve" the problem, but not the real problem of OP. It is like advising to plug the devices in two different computers.

Comment: @AliChen, one of the ways this happens is that endpoint zero is active on two devices. Plugging into different controllers roots is NOT in anyway like using two computers.

Comment: Endpoint zero can't happen on two devices unless the board is screwed electrically and resets both devices, or glitches generate false USB reset signaling without causing port disconnect, for the same electrical reasons. This is exactly the purpose of all questions to OP, it is unclear what OP is doing.

Comment: Endpoint zero can be screwed as some implementations don't have a SIE engine, it's all implemented in firmware. You can see this in FPGA implementations too.

Comment: I re-iterate: screwing of endpoint zero will lead only to failure to enumerate this particular device. SIE is a must to obey USB protocol, regardless of how it is implemented. Firmware will only add long delays. And if a design can't ACK/NAK in 1.7 us, it doesn't have a valid SIE, and should be junked/re-designed.